# How to get namespace of xml

Tags: java, xml

I have this xml:

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(
        "<data:RobCtiAifoData xmlns:data=\"urn:cz:isvs:rob:schemas:RobDotazyData:v1\" xmlns:reg=\"urn:cz:isvs:reg:schemas:RegTypy:v1\" xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:urn=\"urn:cz:isvs:rob:schemas:RobUnivDotazy:v1\"><data:Aifo a=\"b\">1</data:Aifo><data:VyuzitiPoskytnuti>vyuziti</data:VyuzitiPoskytnuti> </data:RobCtiAifoData>"
                .getBytes());

// InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes());
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = db.parse(is);
Node node = document.getDocumentElement();
```

when wanna get name of element without namespace so I wanna call substring of name of element withou prefix

`node.getNodeName()` gives me **`data:VyuzitiPoskytnuti`**
and `node.getNamespaceURI()` or `node.getPrefix()` gives me just **`null`**. So how I can get prefix of node ?

Comment: "when wanna get name of element without namespace so I wanna call substring of name of element withou prefix" - that's completely incomprehensible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try enabling namespace support:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
```

From the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setNamespaceAware%28boolean%29) for `setNamespaceAware`:

> Specifies that the parser produced by this code will provide support for XML namespaces. By default the value of this is set to `false`